# Problem connecting gateway to internet through cellular connection

Tags: networking, dns, network-interface, internet, lte

I'm by no means an experienced person in this regard.

#### Context, if you find it helpful

We are developing an IoT solution for telemetry purposes. The device that retrieve the data to send it to the cloud is a custom Debian (9) gateway developed by the same company that provide us the software that help us achieve this kind of things (Moxa).

My problem is that I can't connect it to the internet through the cellular (LTE), so this is the reason I can't install libraries in the device (like the Google Cloud SDK).

### Situation

The device has the following interfaces:

```
$ sudo ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:90:e8:7c:e0:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.3.127/24 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:90:e8:7c:e0:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.4.127/24 brd 192.168.4.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::290:e8ff:fe7c:e02f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
21: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c6:d4:e8:d9:64:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.127.34.103/32 scope global usb0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c4d4:e8ff:fed9:643e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

According to the docs, the `eth0` is for WAN and `eth1` for LAN purposes.

This is the content of my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto eth0 eth1 lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.3.127
        network 192.168.3.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.3.255
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.4.127
        network 192.168.4.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.4.255
```

And this is the content of the `/etc/resolv.conf`. Those values are the DNS of the carrier (Movistar Peru):

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 200.48.225.130
nameserver 200.48.225.146
```

By the way, I've already set up the correct APN so the SIM should work (I did it through the admin panel of the gateway).

This are the results of ping:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable

$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Of course there might be errors in this config. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

---

## Update

As requested, this is what the `ip r`/`ip route` returned:

```
$ ip r
192.168.3.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.3.127 linkdown
192.168.4.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.4.127
```

Also, this is what the manual states regarding the ethernet interfaces:

> The `ETH0` Ethernet interface is used for the `WAN` and the `ETH1`
> interface is used for the `LAN`. The default IP addresses are:
>
> ```
> eth0=192.168.3.127
> eth1=192.168.4.127
> ```

And:

> Interfaces of your eligible device could include:
>
> - tun0: VPN Tunnel // not using this
> - wlan0: Wi-Fi // Our required device doesn't include this module
> - wwan0: Cellular  // < -- The one we should use to get/send data to the cloud
> - eth0: Ethernet (usually LAN1 when the default setting is WAN).

A diagram that might help:

[image]

Comment: Can you reach the gateway? What does your routing table look like (`ip r`)? Do you have any firewalls or routers to go through?

Comment: What does it mean "eth0 is for WAN"? Presumably the cellular interface, `usb0`, is the WAN. Perhaps a simple network diagram would help make it clearer. Also, show your route table with `ip route`

Comment: @kaylum you can't tell what is WAN as OP is only showing private IPs

Comment: @user1794469 That's why I said "presumably". The cellular interface is usually WAN unless it is somehow an internal private cellular LAN network (unlikely). So that's why clarification has been sought.

Comment: @kaylum oops, yeah of course

Comment: @user1794469 The device is here in the office, that's why I couldn't update the response until now. I have now access to the device if you need more info about/from the gateway.

Comment: @kaylum The device is here in the office, that's why I couldn't update the response until now. I have now access to the device if you need more info about/from the gateway.

Comment: Which machine are you configuring? Is it G, the gateway? I think you want to be able to send data from D pass through G and access some machine or service on C. Though I'm not sure which machine you are issuing commands from. Is this correct?

Comment: @user1794469 I have issues configuring the gateway. That is the main unit. The devices just send data, this data is collected and handled by the gatway.

Comment: So D doesn't matter then, right? You just need G to have access to the internet? What is G connected to? You probably just need to set G to use DHCP on the interface that connects to C. If that's `eth1` see if `sudo dhclient eth1` works.

Comment: @user1794469 I mean yes it matters, but not in this case because in order to connect to D the G needs internet access. At the moment, the Gateway has disabled the DHCP, the DNS are fixed to the ones of our internet provider

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103355/discussion-between-user1794469-and-kenny-horna).